# C++ shared library called from C

Tags: c++, c, shared-libraries, portability

I have a shared library written in C++. It exports a visible interface made of `extern "C"` functions which create, destroy and manipulate opaque types.

Now, I'd like to have a pure C program which uses this library.

Can I do this (platform independently) ? When will the C++ runtime and the C++ static objects get initialized if `main` is not written in C++ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The initialization phase is platform dependent.
In the case of Linux, dynamically loaded libraries can have specially declared symbols that are automatically called by `dlopen()` when the library is loaded.

See the manpage for `dlopen(3)`, section *The obsolete symbols init() and fini()* for more info.

Static initializers are implicitly marked as `__attribute__((constructor))`, so in general you don't have to do anything special to have them called when the shared library is loaded. I suspect this is the same or similar on other platforms.

Comment: Addendum. (glibc:) init/fini is provided by the runtime environment (crtS.o) and is used for initialization of static duration objects and calling functions marked __attribute__((constructor)), so overriding init/fini on your own can lead to problems, including bailing out due to a double symbol definition.

Comment: @jørgensen: Could that be the reason why they're deprecated?

Answer (score 4):

> Can I do this (platform independently) ?

The library loading is a platform dependent operation.

> When will the C++ runtime and the C++ static objects get initialized
>   if main is not written in C++ ?

Doesn't matter. They will be initialized before the main is entered.

Comment: Well, a library can still be (manually) loaded after `main` has entered. And "`They will be initialized before the main is entered.` " is a misconception. It's implementation-defined whether the initialisation of a static object occurs before `main` is entered, or any time before its first usage. But for all practical purposes, yes, they're initialised before `main`, or right after the library is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, shared library systems have an entry point of their own in which to do this work, not `main` but DLLs have a `DLLMain` where the implementation can put such code. However, in the general case, it is none of your business and it's the job of whatever compiler you used to deal with this issue.